# how to do this raw sql query using active record query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using active record query how do I do the following sql query?

```
sql = "select * from events 
inner join places on events.place_id = places.id 
inner join users on events.user_id = users.id"
where events.id = #{event_id}
```

I've tried

```
Event.joins(:user, :place).includes(:user, place).find(event_id)
```

This almost does what I want however does select events.* and not select *.*

I then tried

```
Event.joins(:user, :place).select('*.*')
```

This however returns an ActiveRelation object and I'm not sure how to get my results out of this.

I've also tried

```
Event.joins(:user, :place).find(event_id)
```

and this throws an error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
```

Not sure what else to try. Is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Comment: An active relation object is what you want. Just call a method on it that will make the query execute - eg `all` or `each` or `to_a` (to convert it to an array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Event.joins(:user, :place).where("events.id = ?", event_id).select("events.*, users.*, places.*")
```

Comment: The problem is this returns event.* and isn't the same as the raw sql query I'm trying to recreate. i want the query to return all the fields from the joined tables as well in a single query.

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how do I then access the joined tables from the results returned? It seems to just return the Event, I don't see any of the joined columns.

The raw sql query returns  a list of hashes that contain all the joined columns for each result returned, I don't see where the equivalent data is, in the active record query result you gave.

Comment: I suggest you go through this article: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html. I do not see a reason to imitate that sql query using activerecord. When you `includes` association, activerecord does not make another db query to fetch that association.